# Is there multilevel structure in hibernate

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, hibernate, spring-mvc

How to design following structure of beans if I have to Question which has sub Questions and all questions and subquestions has respective answer. Structure is like

[Structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Rdw5l.png)

How I can design this structure in hibernate for achieving functionality in spring boot.

Answer (score 2):

If we take into consideration that these are 3 different tables, what I would think would be an entity of `Question`

```
@Entity
@Table("question")
public class Question
```

then an entity of `SubQuestion`

```
@Entity
@Table("sub_question")
public class SubQuestion
```

with `ManyToOne` assosiation

```
  @ManyToOne(fetch=FetchType.LAZY)
  @JoinColumn(name="QUESTION_ID")
  private Question question;
```

and finally a generic class `GenericAnswer`

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "answer")
@Inheritance(strategy = InheritanceType.SINGLE_TABLE)
@DiscriminatorColumn(name = "question", discriminatorType = DiscriminatorType.STRING)
public class GenericAnswer {
```

which will be extended by 2 classes, `QuestionAnswer` and `SubQuestionAnswer`

These 2 classes have a discriminator column to distinguish the table they refer to (question or sub_question)

```
@DiscriminatorValue("question")
@Entity
public class QuestionAnswer extends GenericAnswer {

@ManyToOne(fetch=FetchType.LAZY)
@JoinColumn(name="QUESTION_ID")
private Question question;
```

and

```
@DiscriminatorValue("sub_question")
@Entity
public class SubQuestionAnswer extends GenericAnswer {

@ManyToOne(fetch=FetchType.LAZY)
@JoinColumn(name="QUESTION_ID")
private SubQuestion subQuestion;
```

Hope this helps you.

Comment: What will be the scenario if Subquestion is optional field for some questions?